# Passing argument from main thread to thread. When thread exits main thread has its reset to 0. Why?

Tags: c++, multithreading, arguments, pthreads

For a uni assignment we have to estimate pi using the monte carlo method and implement it in threads. My code is below and everything seems to be fine except when my created thread ends the variable numberOfPointsPerThread gets reset to 0. Does anybody know why that is? I thought each thread has its own version of the stack so when it exits it should leave the main threads stack clear. Or am I wrong?

```
void * threadMonteCarlo(void * param)
{
    int r = 5000;
    int numberOfPointsInCircle = 0; 
    int x, y;

    srand(time(NULL));

    for(int i=0; i<*((int *) param); i++)
    {
        x = rand() % r + 1;
        y = rand() % r + 1;
        if (x*x + y*y <= r*r)
        {
            numberOfPointsInCircle++;
        }
    }   

    cout << "Thread working" << endl;
    pthread_exit((void*)numberOfPointsInCircle);
}

int main(void)
{
    pthread_t child;
    int numberOfThreads = 1;
    int numberOfPointsPerThread = 9;
    int x;
    int collectedResult;
    double pi;

    pthread_create(&child, NULL, threadMonteCarlo, (void *)&numberOfPointsPerThread);
    pthread_join(child, (void **)&x);
    cout << "Returning value from thread is " << x <<endl;

    collectedResult = x;

    cout << "numberOfPointsPerThread = " << numberOfPointsPerThread << endl;

    pi = 4*double(collectedResult)/double(numberOfPointsPerThread*numberOfThreads);

    cout << "Estimate of pi is " << pi << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean `numberOfPointsInCircle` is getting reset to zero? That would make sense to me.

Comment: Why are you casting an integer to a pointer when you call `pthread_exit()`? Did you mean `(void*)&numberOfPointInCircle`?

Comment: When I cout << numberOfPointsInCircle I get a correctish number (it is random).

Comment: Okay @williamRosenbloom I know see what you mean. How do I return the value  of numberOfPointsInCircle back to the main thread? I'm assuming it is know zero because the stack of that thread no longer exists.

Comment: @user3223954 You can either `malloc` it (which is not recommended) or you can pass a pointer to `numberOfPointsInCircle` into your thread and adjust its value instead of returning it. Again, I would recommend the latter.

Comment: Make `x` a `void *` and move the cast here: `collectedResult = (int) x;`.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that `x` is an `int` which is not large enough to hold the `void*` that is being written to in the `pthread_join()` call:

```
pthread_join(child, (void **)&x);
```

The undefined behavior that results is apparently trashing `numberOfPointsPerThread`.

Comment: And the code is probably running on a big-endian machine, rather than a little-endian (Intel) machine, so the problem shows up where it might otherwise be concealed — I think.