# Collecting results returned from thread

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, pthreads

doing an assignment for uni where we need to use threads to approximate pi. The threads count the points inside a circle and return the result when done. The main thread needs to collect these results and run an equation. Everything seems to be in working order except I cannot add to my collected result it instead just outputs the same result as the return value from a thread. Any ideas?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <pthread.h>

using namespace std;

void * threadMonteCarlo(void * param)
{
    int r = 10000;
    int numberOfPointsInCircle = 0; 
    int x, y;

    srand(time(NULL));

    for(int i=0; i<*((int *) param); i++)
    {
        x = rand() % r + 1;
        y = rand() % r + 1;
        if (x*x + y*y <= r*r)
        {
            numberOfPointsInCircle++;
        }
    }   
    cout << "In this thread the points found inside the circle were: " << numberOfPointsInCircle << endl;
    pthread_exit((void *)numberOfPointsInCircle);
}

int main(void)
{
    int numberOfThreads = 4;
    pthread_t thread[numberOfThreads];

    int numberOfPointsPerThread = 1000000000/numberOfThreads;
    int collectedResult = 0;
    int x = 0;

    double pi;

    for(int i=0; i<numberOfThreads; i++)
    {
        pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, threadMonteCarlo, (void *)&numberOfPointsPerThread);
    }

    for(int i=0; i<numberOfThreads; i++)
    {
        collectedResult = collectedResult + x;
        cout << "The total result is: " << collectedResult << endl;
        pthread_join(thread[i], (void **)&x);
        cout << "The retrieved result was " << x << endl;
    }

    pi = 4*double(collectedResult)/(numberOfPointsPerThread*numberOfThreads);

    cout << "Estimate of pi is " << pi << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing argument from main thread to thread. When thread exits main thread has its reset to 0. Why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34364421/passing-argument-from-main-thread-to-thread-when-thread-exits-main-thread-has-i)

Comment: @EOF Same code different problem now.

Comment: You have not fixed the undefined behavior pointed out in the answer to the old question. There can be no sane new answer as long as the program exhibits undefined behavior.